# Wordpress function theme_include_lib()

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a problem with WordPress I am receiving an error:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function theme_include_lib() in /home/peartree/public_html/wp-content/themes/PeartreeArt6/comments.php on line 51

and here is the secton of code:

```
// comment form
theme_ob_start();
$args = array();
if (theme_get_option('theme_comment_use_smilies')) {
    function theme_comment_form_field_comment($form_field) {
        theme_include_lib('smiley.php');
        return theme_get_smilies_js() . '<p class="smilies">' .     theme_get_smilies() . '</p>' . $form_field;
    }

    add_filter('comment_form_field_comment',     'theme_comment_form_field_comment');
 }
comment_form();
```

Comment: Is `PeartreeArt6` a child theme, or the main theme?   The problem is that the function `theme_include_lib()` does not exist.

Comment: I believe this is the case however I cannot be certain, how can I double check? Thanks.

Comment: The code in my answer is probably the best bet.  Let me know if it works for you, or if there are other errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found this code [out in the wild](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/different-sylecss-for-home-page), which may or may not help.  Try including this code in your /home/peartree/public_html/wp-content/themes/PeartreeArt6/functions.php file and see if it helps.  I first check whether the function exists, just in case it is already defined elsewhere.

```
if (!function_exists('theme_include_lib')){
  function theme_include_lib($name){
    if (function_exists('locate_template')){
      locate_template(array('library/'.$name), true);
    } else {
      theme_locate_template(array('library/'.$name), true);
    }
  }
}
```